# ajax push server

Tags: ajax, jquery, push

Alright, I recently wrote a ajax push script which had php on the backend sleeping while waiting for someone to make an update. However, the sleeping processes took up a lot of cpu. Any ideas on how I can prevent this? I am guessing I will have to either find a program which can do the sleeping with threads or write my own in python or c++ which I am not very familiar with. I am using ajax push for a browser based game so people can play it in real time but I think if I get too many sleeping processes on the backend it would overload the server.

Comment: Two examples available at http://www.udaparts.com/document/Tutorial/httppush.htm and http://www.udaparts.com/document/Tutorial/slpush.htm

Comment: PHP is not the best language for this, by far. Use Node.js, pyhon/twisted or or something like that.

Comment: Yes, php is not the best but I have a great working daemon now with no memory leaks in php; however; a slight issue with multiple tabs in the same browser; made as a different ticket. As for Node.js, I have tried to install node.js 3 different times; twice on centos and once on ubuntu which was suppose to be ready for node.js and it still did not install right; tried several tutorials. As for python/twisted; that is the route I am looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research last night, I found this as the answer for the server side.
Then write a php script for the client side.
Then have ajax call the client which calls the server.
Only problem is some of the extensions have to be manually installed.

http://php-mag.net/itr/online_artikel/psecom,id,484,nodeid,114.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want some kind of long-polling stuff -- you should search for the term "[comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)".

For instance, here are a couple of posts that might interest you :

- [Is there some way to PUSH data from web server to browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995/is-there-some-way-to-push-data-from-web-server-to-browser)
- [Online tutorials for implementing comets (server push)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824604/online-tutorials-for-implementing-comets-server-push)
- [Using comet with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php)
- [Problem of choosing comet server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250850/problem-of-choosing-comet-server)
- [Comet & PHP: How to use Comet with a PHP Chat System ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190744/comet-php-how-to-use-comet-with-a-php-chat-system)

Still, one might say that PHP, because of its non-threaded model, I suppose, is not the best language/technology for that kind of stuff... And maybe you'll end up looking to another technology for that part of your site...

For instance, you can take a look at :

- [Choosing and deploying a comet server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621802/choosing-and-deploying-a-comet-server)

Answer (score 0):

some links about reverse http:
[reverse http 1](http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/reverse-http/)
[making-real-time-web-real-time](http://t0rxon.blogspot.com/2009/02/making-real-time-web-real-time.html)
[reverse http 2](http://www.reversehttp.net/)
[rest-requires-asynchronous-notification](http://kirkwylie.blogspot.com/2008/12/rest-requires-asynchronous-notification.html)